# Remove DataRepeater Control bottom line in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

how can I remove the bottom border line of data control item in `DataRepeater` control:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separator which you see in `DataRepeater` control between items, is a drawing on non-client area of `DataRepeaterItem` control.

You can find those `DataRepeaterItem` and handle those [`WM_NCPAINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145212(v=vs.85).aspx) messages and draw a line with the same color as item `BackColor` or any other color which you want from `(0, Height-1)` to `(Width-1, Height-1)`.

**Implementation**

To do so, we create a class deriving from [`NativeWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx) which enables us to handle messages of another window, if we assign handle of other window to it:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class DataRepeaterItemHelper : NativeWindow
{
    private DataRepeaterItem item;
    private const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
    public DataRepeaterItemHelper(DataRepeaterItem repeaterItem)
    {
        item = repeaterItem;
        this.AssignHandle(item.Handle);
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCPAINT)
        {
            var hdc = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHdcInternal(hdc))
            using (var p = new Pen(item.BackColor, 1))
                g.DrawLine(p, 0, item.Height - 1, item.Width - 1, item.Height - 1);
            ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hdc);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we handle `DrawItem` event of `DataRepeater` and check if we didn't have created a `DataRepeaterItemHelper` for `e.DataRepeaterItem` we create one. It helps drawing the separator with the same color as item back color. Also after loading data into `DataRepeater` we should create `DataRepeaterItemHelper` for the first items which `DrawItem` event doesn't fire for them. To keep track of items which we created a `DataRepeaterItemHelper` for them, we keep handled items in a `List<DataRepeaterItem>`:

```
new List<DataRepeaterItem> items = new List<DataRepeaterItem>();
void HandleItem(DataRepeaterItem item)
{
    if (items.Contains(item))
        return;
    var handler = new DataRepeaterItemHelper(item);
    items.Add(item);
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load data and put data in dataRepeater1.DataSource
    var db = new TestDBEntities();
    this.dataRepeater1.DataSource = db.Category.ToList();
    this.dataRepeater1.Controls.OfType<DataRepeaterItem>().ToList()
        .ForEach(item => HandleItem(item));
    this.dataRepeater1.DrawItem += dataRepeater1_DrawItem;
}
void dataRepeater1_DrawItem(object sender, DataRepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HandleItem(e.DataRepeaterItem);
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

**Note:**

- When applying the solution, don't forget to attach `Form1_Load` event to `Load` event of form. You don't need to attach `dataRepeater1_DrawItem` to `DrawItem` event. It's been attached in `Form1_Load` using code.
- You can encapsulate the logic in a derived `DataRepeater` control.

Comment: I've found that a variation on this answer also works for overwriting the DataRepeater's dynamically colored, unremovable border.